# redirect 403 error using .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I want to redirect any 403 using .htaccess, but it does not seem to work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 403 notfound.html
RewriteRule notfound.html
```

All help appreciated.

Thanks Jean

Answer (score 1):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /notfound.html
```

You don't need mod_rewrite for this.
It would only bee needed if you want to catch any error to a specific error page.